# Dapper contrib get data having varchar primary key

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, dapper, dapper-contrib

I have a varchar key column. I am trying to use the `Get` method of Dapper contrib. I get an exception:

> Get only supports an entity with a [Key] or an [ExplicitKey] property.

My Entity:

```
public class State : BaseModel
{
    [Key]       
    public string state_code { get; set; }
    public string state_name { get; set; }
    public int language_code { get; set; }
    public bool is_active { get; set; }
}
```

My Dapper Method

```
public IEnumerable<State> FindByCode(string code)
{
    return this._db.Get<State>(code);
}
```

I even tried to set Explicit Key, still I get the same error.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.KeyAttribute` or `Dapper.Contrib.Extensions.KeyAttribute`?

Comment: Dapper.Contrib.Extensions.KeyAttribute

Comment: What do you have inside BaseModel? Are you sure you have tried with [ExplicitKey] from Dapper.Contrib.Extensions ?

Comment: Right now there is nothing in BaseModel. It is created for general functionality. It is part of architecture. And Ya i had tried with [ExplicitKey] from Dapper.Contrib.Extensions but it give me same exception.

Comment: @ros2008 Why do you return IEnumerable<State> since Get() returns only one object? Btw for me it's working with both [Key] and [ExplicitKey]

Comment: Your primary key is of varchar type?

Comment: @ros2008 yes, it's varchar

Comment: can you please tell me which version of Dapper.Contrib you are using in your application?

Comment: @ros2008 1.60.1

Comment: How did you create the database? If you combine EF Core and `Dapper.Contrib`, you need to use both keys with  `[Key]` under `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` and `Dapper.Contrib.Extensions`.

Answer (score 3):

Try to check your code like:

```
public class State : BaseModel
{
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Key]
    [Dapper.Contrib.Extensions.Key]
    public string state_code { get; set; }
    public string state_name { get; set; }
    public int language_code { get; set; }
    public bool is_active { get; set; }
}
```